# How to hide <UNIVERSAL> <class 'scapy3k.asn1.asn1.ASN1_Class_metaclass'> when sniffing with scapy3k?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scapy

I'm trying to sniff using scapy3k, but it prints " " a lot and I don't know how to hide it

def dns_sniff():
    sniff(lfilter=lambda pack: DNS in pack and pack[UDP].sport == 53, prn=lambda pack: pack[DNS].summary().split("'")[1])

Comment: Use Scapy instead. It'll fix it

Comment: I have to use scapy3k... No way of hiding it without using scapy?

Comment: I fail to see why you would need scapy3k. Note that Scapy now supports Python 3